# C# How to get a different color form a loop for each item?

Tags: c#

I have more than 10 items wanna using Pen to Draw Ellipse in my Graphics.

Question is how can i make a loop to get different color for each item?

```
 graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Maroon, 2f), x, y, 2, 2);
```

Color class using String to show each color, I wanna something like:

```
String colorName;

for(int i=0, i<ItemsLength; i++)
{
    colorName = getColorNmae(data[i]);
}

graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(colorName, 2f), x, y, 2, 2);
```

Comment: any random color? Does this code compile?

Comment: Make a collection of your desired colors.  Cycle though said collection.

Comment: Yeah..but I want each item gets a own color, no duplicate..

Comment: So don't put duplicate colors in the collection.  Build a collection of 10 colors and cycle through them, assigning each color only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, create your list of colours, eg:

```
var colors = new List<Color>
{
    Color.Red,
    Color.Blue,
    ...
    Color.Maroon
}
```

Then, assuming you have ten colours, you can use `i % 10` to get a number between 0 and 9 to loop repeatedly around the colours:

```
for(var i = 0, i < ItemsLength; i++)
{
    var x = derive x from items[i]
    var y = derive y from items[i]
    graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(colors[i % colors.Count], 2f), x, y, 2, 2);
}
```

Comment: To make it more flexible: `colors[i%colors.Count]`

Comment: @CSharpie, that's embarrassing, I didn't think of that! Very good advice. Answer updated accordingly.